# Combine CompletableFuture

Tags: java, completable-future

I have this code:

```java
CompletableFuture<ApplicationUserDto> byUserName = applicationUserService
                .findByUserName(getCurrentApplicationUserName());

CompletableFuture<List<FocusDto>> focuses = focusService.findMine(byUserName.join().getFacilities());

CompletableFuture.allOf(byUserName, focuses).join();

Iterable<IdmDataFacade> facilities = idmService.lookupFacilities(new HashSet<>(byUserName.join().getFacilities())).toIterable();
```

So in `focusService.findMine`
i'm dependent on the result from
`applicationUserService.findByUserName(getCurrentApplicationUserName())`

But in my frontend tests all data is displayed in the right way and manner.

I´ve read about `thenCompose` method on `CompletableFuture` so i tested this code:

```java
CompletableFuture<ApplicationUserDto> byUserName = applicationUserService
                .findByUserName(getCurrentApplicationUserName());

CompletableFuture<List<FocusDto>> focuses = byUserName
                .thenComposeAsync((result) -> focusService.findMine(result.getFacilities()));

CompletableFuture.allOf(byUserName, focuses).join();

Iterable<IdmDataFacade> facilities = idmService.lookupFacilities(new HashSet<>(byUserName.join().getFacilities())).toIterable();
```

Both code snippets lead to the exact same results. In the log i can see the threads being used. Even these are equal.

So my questions:

1. Is `CompletableFuture` so smart to know that it has to wait for `byUserName` completion to fill in the parameter in `focusService.findMine(byUserName.join().getFacilities())`
2. Which piece of code is better to be used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1. Is CompletableFuture so smart to know that it has to wait for byUserName completion to fill in the parameter in focusService.findMine(byUserName.join().getFacilities())

That's the purpose of the `.join`: wait until the result is ready and return it. If you write code like this:

```
CompletableFuture<ApplicationUserDto> byUserName = applicationUserService
                .findByUserName(getCurrentApplicationUserName());

CompletableFuture<List<FocusDto>> focuses = focusService.findMine(byUserName.join().getFacilities());
```

You are telling the application to block the execution and wait for `byUserName` to complete before calling `findMine`, so that you have the parameter for `.findMine`.

This also means that you don't need to call `.allOf` after, because you already know that `byUserName` is completed.

You could rewrite everything like this:

```
Iterable<IdmDataFacade> facilities = applicationUserService
                .findByUserName(getCurrentApplicationUserName())
                .thenCompose(byUserNameResult -> focusService
                    .findMine(byUserNameResult.getFacilities())
                    .thenApply(findMineResult -> idmService
                        .lookupFacilities(new HashSet<>(byUserNameResult.getFacilities())).toIterable()
                    )
                )
                .join();
```

> 2. Which piece of code is better to be used?

Who knows? It depends what you are trying to achieve. Usually, it doesn't make sense to `.join` after every `CompletionStage` if you are using them.

Comment: "Usually, it doesn't make sense to .join after every CompletionStage if you are using them."? Does that mean i should only join() if i want to have the result immediately? In my case i use all CompletableFuture results in a thymeleaf generated html view.

Comment: Why are you using `CompletionStage` if you need to wait for the result to be ready before continuing? Anyway, I wouldn't read to much into my comment, there might be use cases I'm not familiar with. The point here is that when you use `.join`, you are asking the app to wait until the result is ready.